# Have subclass inherit non-default __init__ values from an instantiated main class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

How can I have a subclass that inherits not just `__init__` variables from the main class, but also inherits the instantiated values from an instantiated main class.

For example, say I have these classes:

```
class MainClass(object):
    def __init__(self, mainVar1=None, mainVar2=None):
        self.mainVar1 = mainVar1
        self.mainVar2 = mainVar2

class SubClass(MainClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__()
        self.subVar1 = -1
```

And I do this:

```
main = MainClass(mainVar1=1, mainVar2=2)
sub = SubClass()
print(sub.mainVar1)
```

This prints out `None` and not `1` because `sub` calls the `__init__` of `MainClass` in which `mainVar1` by default is set to `None`.

What I'd like to do is instantiate `SubClass` in such a way that it gets the input values used to instantiate `MainClass`, so that `print(sub.mainVar1)` prints `1` instead of `None`.

I want to do this without repeating the same variables when instantiating the classes:

```
main = MainClass(mainVar1=1, mainVar2=2)
# This is what I'm trying to avoid.
sub = SubClass(mainVar1=1, mainVar2=2)
print(sub.mainVar1)
```

Is this possible? Is this a terrible design choice? What's the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**

*Concrete Example*

I have a class called `ServerTools` that provides functions for accessing data on a server. This is my `MainClass` class in the example above. To instantiate this class I need a `username`, `password`, and `server_url`.

I then have a subclass called `Docs` that creates a document from data on the server. To instantiate this class I need `username`, `password`, `server_url`, and some other arguments. This subclass needs the functions from the main class `ServerTools` to access data on the server.

My thought process was to have `Docs` be a tool in `ServerTools`, in which a document cannot be created without instantiating `ServerTools`. I'm not sure whether `Docs` should be a subclass, an inner-class, or something else entirely.

Comment: So you want to add a 2nd constructor that takes a `MainClass` instance as input and copies all of its attributes?

Comment: It isnt obvious how it would work exactly. What if you have multiple instances of the parent class?  The subclass carries around no information about what arguments you have passed to a parant classes' instances, neither does the parent class for that matter.

Comment: And what if you have _no_ instances of the parent class? Your subclass initializer can’t read into some alternate universe where everyone uses zeppelins instead of planes and you constructed a parent class instance, because that usually leads to Cybermen attacks. I think this is a sign that a subclass isn’t actually what you’re looking for, but rather a separate class whose instances _own_ a `MainClass` instance rather than _being_ one.

Comment: @abarnert Essentially, I only want `SubClass` to exist if `MainClass` exists, so I think a separate class that owns the instance is more of the idea I'm going for, but I'm not sure how to do that and inherit the `__init__` variables and class functions from the passed instance of `MainClass`.

Comment: I think you're still thinking about things wrong. A class doesn't just "exist" or "not exist". You can have any number of instances of a class. There can be 1, or 0, or 69105 instances. And the instances change over time. If you're thinking about your classes as if they were instances, maybe they shouldn't even be classes in the first place. But it's very hard to figure out where you're confused, and point you in the right direction, with an abstract toy example like this. Can you give us a simple but concrete example, with meaningful objects? That might make it easier.

Comment: @abarnert Just added a concrete example. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your actual design, it sounds like you don't want subclasses at all.

Think about your object model in terms of the actual objects you're modeling, and the relationships between them, and it's usually clearer how the classes should be written.

You have a `ServerTools` class. Instances of this class represent a server, or a connection to a server, or something like that.

You have a `Docs` class. Instances of this class represent documents on a server.

Each `Docs` object is not a server, so it should not *be* a `ServerTools` instance. But each `Docs` object has a server that it's stored on, so it should *have* a `ServerTools` object.

---

So, you probably want to model it like this:

```
class ServerTools(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, server_url):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.server_url = server_url

class Docs(object):
    def __init__(self, server, path):
        self.server = server
        self.path = path

myserver = ServerTools('me', 'swordfish', 'smb://chico.example.com')
mydocs = Docs(myserver, '/Horse/Feathers')
```

---

Alternatively, if you rarely have a need for `ServerTools` objects on their own, and want to create one for each `Docs` object, you might create it in the initializer. To do that, you'd take all of the relevant `ServerTools`-construction arguments as parameters:

```
class Docs(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, url, path):
        self.server = ServerTools(username, password, url)
        self.path = path

mydocs = Docs('me', 'swordfish', 'smb://chico.example.com' '/Horse/Feathers')
```

---

As a side note, I'm not sure why you wanted these arguments to have default values of `None`. Why would you want to create a `ServerTools` with no `server_url`? So, I left the defaults off. But you can add them back on if you have a reason to use them.

Comment: So `Docs` also needs to inherit methods from `ServerTools`, so the only change in the code you provided would be to pass `ServerTools` instead of `object` through `Docs` like so: `class Docs(ServerTools):`, correct?

Comment: @colossatr0n Why would `Docs` need to inherit methods? What server method does a docs object need to support?

Comment: Besides just connecting to a server, `ServerTools` contains methods to make `get` and `push` requests to the server. `Docs` literally creates a `.html` document by pulling data from the server and then writing that data to a `.html` file, so it needs the `get` methods from `ServerTools`.

Comment: Following abarnert's advice, I've set things up a little differently. I now have a `Server` class that stores server credentials. I have a `ServerTools` class that has methods for making `get` and `push` requests to a server and takes a `Server` object as an argument, and I have a `Doc` class that inherits the functions from `ServerTools` and takes a `Server` object as an argument. You have been super helpful abarnert. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass through arguments using splat and splatty splat operators:

```
class SubClass(MainClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.subVar1 = -1

sub = SubClass(mainVar1=1, mainVar2=2)
```

Remember that `sub` is an instance of `MainClass` by inheritance: `isinstance(sub, MainClass)` will return `True`. You do not need a separate instance of `MainClass` at all.

As an extended example, even if you had a method called `meth1` in `MainClass` and overrode it in `SubClass`, you can still call it like this:

```
MainClass.meth1(sub, ...)
```